# Can I use this Spotify wrapper without Maven/Gradle?

Tags: java

Is there any way that I would be able to use this wrapper class "https://github.com/spotify-web-api-java/spotify-web-api-java" in a Java project that doesn't implement Maven or Gradle? And if so how would I be able to do it?

Tried to google it but wasn't able to find any answers.

Comment: Just curious... why don't you want to use Maven or Gradle? They are the standard Java / JVM build tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absolute, Yes you can. But it will be a very, very hard task.

Look at the dependencies in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/spotify-web-api-java/spotify-web-api-java/blob/master/pom.xml) file:

```xml
[...]
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
      <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
      <version>1.29</version>
    </dependency>
[...]
```

It means: to succeed, download:
`2.17.0` version of `jackson-databind` project, where you can find it,
`2.10.1` version of `gson`,
`1.29` version of `nv-i18n`
[...]

and the dependencies of these projects too, if they have any
(and surely they have plenty).

Maven and Gradle aren't something a program implements,
they are tools to download and setup correctly all `jar` that are part of an application together.
You need one of these tools to build your program.

You cannot, I think, escape learning and using Maven.
More than 90% of existing Java projects use it.